# Need Suggestion | IIS Slow | 1 GB Memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, iis, architecture

we have lot of master data which we were using in differnet work flows , so instead of calling them individually ( multiple calls ) ,  we have done all calls for frequent data in global. asax and strored the data in  iis cache .

It was good but as the data size increased and number of calls were taking lot of time so we have changed the design and create a window service which will call service and store the data in app fabric cache , so the data is present upfront for web applications

now on first of web application , we will get the data from app fabric cache and store in IIS cache , it used to be very fast as data was there in app fabric cache

but now as the data size got increased and now when we are storing in IIS it become almost 1GB  which is slowing down IIS .

Could be great if can some provide input on below scenario

a. what is the best pattern or dsign for above problem 
b. is it adivisable to have that much data in IIS cache ?
c. If it is slwoing down IIS , then how to increase the size

Any pointers are highly apreciated

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: Can some one provide valueable inputss

Answer (score 0):

Curious why you would store data in App Fabric and IIS as well? App Fabric should be enough right? The nice thing about App Fabric is that it is a distributed cache which means you can install it on another node/computer and share the data across several machines.

I would try to remove the IIS caching layer and just use App Fabric. It will scale better and make your design simpler.

Comment: Getting data from app fabric cache will also be  slow as it cost seraliazation also